# Can't open ipynb juypter notebook file, crashed on a large df

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Panicking.

Spend a long time working on code in Juypter Notebook on macbook (Anaconda) and i accidentally performed df.fillna(0) on a large df, not knowing it was going to try and load the whole thing in Juypter (i have it set to display all)

It crashed and was unresponsive. Now it's closed and won't load again (i just get the header UI stuff and nothing else - a bar at the top of the webpage shows loading progress but then stalls). The kernel is grey.

Have I just lost all my work? Other files are working as normal. Just managed to get it to partially load (shows me the first couple of cells but page is unresponsive) and i click interupt kernel in a panic to try and get it to just leave me with the code and stop trying to load anything. No luck yet.

Is there any way of retrieving my code? I don't care about any calculations

Thanks

Comment: Jupyter notebooks are just stored as JSON as far as I know. You should be able to open it in a text editor and just pull out the code fields.

Comment: You have not lost all your work. jprebys is right. You can recover the code from the Jupiter notebook (without opening) open it in a text editor. You can also recover the data using a free or charge data recovery tool ( There's a lot but it will take your time. ) [If you file is also somehow deleted (Cannot happen) But if it is, that file recover thing can be used for that as well.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's a bit of a mess in JSON (it's showing all the df info) but i can probably salvage it with time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter notebooks are just stored as JSON. You should be able to open it in a text editor and just pull out the code fields. – answer provided by jprebys
Oct 21 at 13:35